# Copy and Rename with Bat File

Tags: csv, batch-file

I have also posted this question on (https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/copy-and-rename-with-bat-file.1169385/)
I have read a lot of post on this and solved one of my problems for copying and rename a file with the following code, however I still get overwhelmed when trying to understand some of the post on this site about this topic.

```
xcopy "M:\abc.csv" "O:\File"
set HR=%time:~0,2%
set HR=%Hr: =0%
set HR=%HR: =%
rename "O:\File\abc.csv" "x_%date:~10,4%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%_%HR%%time:~3,2%.csv"
```

My output on this is file name = x_YYYY-MM-DD_TTTT.csv, I don't understand how all the variables work, but I need to get this bat file to rename abc.csv file to something like "MM-DD-YYYY-#XXX.csv". The "#" would be an incremental value depending on how many files are renamed in a day(needs to start over the next day), the "XXX" would just be a set text value for every file. The abc.csv will have the same name every day. I started playing with the script but I'm getting stuck. I know I am missing the incremental part.

```
xcopy "M:\abc.csv" "P:\File"
set HR=%time:~0,2%
set HR=%Hr: =0%
set HR=%HR: =%
rename "P:\File\abc.csv" "%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~10,4%XXX.csv"
```

And the last question which will come up down the road, in the folder that I am copying and renaming, they will have 3 files (abc.csv, def.csv, hij.csv) all 3 will be copied and renamed. Same date and incremental format but with different "XXX" text. Do you have all this in one bat file (I am assuming you cant accommodate all of this in the same script, you would have to do separate lines) or do you break it up into 3 different bat files?

I have edited the code with the actual file names and directories, also made a little progress.  When you run the `echo ren` and it outputs multiple lines and they are all the same output "04-28-2021-1Custinfo.txt" does this mean the increment part of code is not working?

```
@echo off
 setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
  for /d /r %%a in (*) do (
    set n=0
    set HR=%time:~0,2%
    set HR=%Hr: =0%
    set HR=%HR: =%   
    pushd "P:\Jarett\SM_TEST\IN"
      for /f "delims=" %%b in (' dir /b /a-d 2^>nul ') do (
        set /a n=n+1
           set num=0!n!
           echo ren "P:\Jarett\SM_TEST\IN\Header3.txt" "%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~10,4%-!num:~-1!%Custinfo.txt"
    )
   popd
  )
pause
```

Well going in circles I feel like, tried this other code I found but when I go to run it a second time it saves the Header3.txt file as Header3.txt in the final destination folder.  I am trying to get it to save it as 04-29-2021-2Custinfo.txt, when I run the bat file for the second time.  Does it matter that I will always be pulling a file Header3.txt, and thats why its not counting?

```
xcopy "M:\Sage 100 Advanced\2018\MAS90\John\MAS_Mirror\SM_TEST\IN\Header3.txt" "P:\Jarett\SM_TEST\IN" 
rem Presumes %date% returns Ddd DD/MM/YYYY so may need adjusting if American format
set today=%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~10,4%
echo %today%
echo "Moving today's files to temp"
mkdir C:\Users\jarett.AS\temp
move %today%* temp
move Header3.txt temp
cd temp
set count=0
for %%x in (Header3.txt) do (set /a count+=1)
set count=00%count%
set count=%count:~-1%
rename "P:\Jarett\SM_TEST\IN\Header3.txt" "%today%-%count%Custinfo.txt"
move *.txt ..
```

This is the code that I finally got to work.  Been playing with it to fully understand everything and trying different things.  I tried renaming the Header3.txt `rename Header3.txt %today%-%count%Custinfo%count%.txt` but it is just renaming it 04-30-2021-1Custinfo1.txt every time.  Could someone point me in the area of where I need to look further into?

```
set today=%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~10,4%
if not exist .\temp mkdir temp
move %today%* temp
xcopy "M:\Sage 100 Advanced\2018\MAS90\John\MAS_Mirror\SM_TEST\IN\Header3.txt" "P:\Jarett\SM_TEST\IN"
move P:\Jarett\SM_TEST\IN\Header3.txt temp
cd temp
set count=0
for %%x in (*.txt) do (set /a count+=1)
set count=00%count%
set count=%count:~-1%
rename Header3.txt %today%-%count%Custinfo.txt
move *.txt P:\Jarett\SM_TEST\IN
```

Comment: The `SET` command syntax is clearly explained in the help file for the `SET` command.  Open up a command prompt and type: `set /?`.

Comment: There are also hundreds of examples of how to properly retrieve the individual components of a date and time in a way which does not depend upon the PC, locale, or user settings. I would advise that you should break down your task into smaller ones, and once you've achieved each of those, try to amalgamate them into one solution. Currently what you require as robust code, is answers to several different questions, (and probably requires futher explanation regarding the correlation between `abc` and `XXX`). _Actual source filenames and their respective resulting destination filenames, perhaps!_

Comment: It may also assist if you could explain if there is a specific reason for using `xcopy.exe` in order to perform a single copy command, as opposed to the internal `copy` command itself. I'd probably advise that it may be better, to copy the file with the new name as a single command, rateher than copy the file as one command, and then rename that file as a separate command afterwards.

Comment: @Compo No idea on reasoning using the `xcopy`, its the first one I got to work on a simple task.  `ROBOCOPY` had also worked but I was struggling on the code after.  There is no correlation between `abc` and  `xxx`, `xxx` will actually be a longer string of text.  This would be the actual source file name "P:\Jarett\SM_TEST\IN\Header.txt" and this would be what I want the output to be "04-28-2021-1Custinfo.txt"

Comment: Open a Command Prompt window, type `copy /?`, press the `[ENTER]` key, and read the output presented. You could also do the same with `rename /?`, `set /?` `xcopy /?`, and `robocopy /?`, for their help and usage information. And please don't ignore the search box, at the top of each page of this site, which should aid you in locating examples for getting your date and time components into your required format.

Comment: @jarett if you have code changes to your question then use the [edit] link to update your question.

Answer (score 0):

Some counts are not clear but if you want changes you can make them.

For example it is not clear how you want the numbering, if that's okay or if you want it for each XXX

try this code:

```
@echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

cls

set sizemax=130
mode con: COLS=%sizemax% LINES=35

rem create "box" macro "Box"
set "Box=call :box"

%Box% "Prepare the test environment ..."
pause

cd %tmp%
mkdir TEST 2>nul
mkdir Jarett 2>nul

set "source_folder=%tmp%\TEST"
set "destination_folder=%tmp%\Jarett"

echo >%source_folder%\abc.csv
echo >%source_folder%\def.csv
echo >%source_folder%\hij.csv

%Box% "Source Folder"
dir %source_folder% & pause

%Box% "Destination Folder"
dir %destination_folder% & pause 

cls
%Box% "Test the script." & pause

:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem set source and destination directory/folder
rem remove rem before using the script in production environment in the following two lines
rem set "source_folder=M:\TEST"
rem set "destination_folder=P:\Jarett"

rem assume all file of type and extension "CSV"

rem create 3 variable for the file name. You can change the name of the file abc,def,hij
set "File1=abc"
set "File2=def"
set "File3=hij"

rem create a map and lookup that associate abc with XXX01, def with XXX02, hij with XXX03. You can change the string XXX01, XXX02, XXX03
SET map=!File1!-XXX01;!File2!-XXX02;!File3!-XXX03;
%Box% "map=!map!" & pause

for %%N in (!File1!, !File2!, !File3!) do (

  rem Set the "today" variable. Choice the correct for you language setting and delete/comment others.
  set "today=%date:~7,2%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~10,4%"
  set "today=%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~10,4%"
  set "today=%date:~3,2%-%date:~0,2%-%date:~6,4%" & rem italian default to MM-DD-YYYY
  %Box% "file:%%N today=!today!" & pause

  rem Count today csv, add 1 and prepare to pad.
  for /f %%f in (' dir !destination_folder!\!today!*.csv /b /a-d 2^>nul ^| find /c /v "" ') do set /a "count=%%f+10001"
  %Box% "file:%%N count=!count!" & pause

  rem prepare time part
  set "now=!time:~0,-3!" & set "now=!now: =0!" & set "now=!now::=.!"
  %Box% "file:%%N now=!now!" & pause

  call :lookup_XXX_map %%N
  %Box% "file:%%N XXX=!XXX!" & pause

  %Box% "move !source_folder!\%%N.csv !destination_folder!\!today!_!now!_!count:~-3!_!XXX!.csv" & pause
  move !source_folder!\%%N.csv !destination_folder!\!today!_!now!_!count:~-3!_!XXX!.csv

  %Box% "Destination Folder"
  dir !destination_folder! & pause
)

echo Exit/End ... & pause

goto :eof
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:box
  set "s=%~1"
  set /A s1=%sizemax%-1, s2=s1-1
  set "l="
  for /L %%B in (1,2,%sizemax%) do set "l=!l!--" & if "!s:~%s1%,1!" == "" set "s= !s! "
  set "s=!s:~1,%s2%!"
  set "l=!l:~0,%s2%!"
  for %%B in ("" "+%l%+" "|%s%|" "+%l%+" "") do echo(%%~B
goto :eof

:lookup_XXX_map
  CALL SET XXX=%%map:*%1-=%%
  SET XXX=%XXX:;=&:%"
goto :eof
```

You must select the correct layout for the "DATE" variable. Then you can run.

When the test is ok then remove the superfluous lines like that:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem set source and destination directory/folder
set "source_folder=M:\TEST"
set "destination_folder=P:\Jarett"

rem assume all file of type and extension "CSV"

rem create 3 variable for the file name. You can change the name of the file abc,def,hij
set "File1=abc"
set "File2=def"
set "File3=hij"

rem create a map and lookup that associate abc with XXX01, def with XXX02, hij with XXX03. You can change the string XXX01, XXX02, XXX03
SET map=!File1!-XXX01;!File2!-XXX02;!File3!-XXX03;

for %%N in (!File1!, !File2!, !File3!) do (

  rem Set the "today" variable. Choice the correct for you language setting and delete/comment others.
  set "today=%date:~7,2%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~10,4%"

  rem Count today csv, add 1 and prepare to pad.
  for /f %%f in (' dir !destination_folder!\!today!*.csv /b /a-d 2^>nul ^| find /c /v "" ') do set /a "count=%%f+10001"

  rem prepare time part
  set "now=!time:~0,-3!" & set "now=!now: =0!" & set "now=!now::=.!"
 
  call :lookup_XXX_map %%N
  
  move !source_folder!\%%N.csv !destination_folder!\!today!_!now!_!count:~-3!_!XXX!.csv

)

echo Exit/End ... & pause

goto :eof

:lookup_XXX_map
  CALL SET XXX=%%map:*%1-=%%
  SET XXX=%XXX:;=&:%"
goto :eof
```